# Implementing security over a network layer that doesn't support security

Tags: networking, network-programming, udp, enet

Foreword: I don't really know much about security or encryption or how it works.

I am developing a small server for a game that uses ENet, which doesn't support higher level things such as security (e.g. SSL/TLS in the TCP world) to, as I think they said, maintain simplicity and embeddability. Supposing that this game requires at least some reasonable degree of security and authentication (e.g. logging in and such), what would be a good approach?

Comment: You'll need some sort of encryption then and maybe asymmetric cryptography may be useful in this scenario for authentication purposes. https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/